# Can't connect to Tryton server

Tags: python, linux, centos7, tryton

I am working on Centos7 , I have isntalle GNU Health and tryton on my VM but I cannot connect to the server via port 8000.
I tried **nmap -PN -p 8000 localhost** command :

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-03 15:23 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8000/tcp closed http-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.26 seconds
```

My trytond.conf file looks like this:

```
[database]
uri = postgresql://localhost:5432
path = /home/gnuhealth/attach

[web]
listen = localhost:8000

[webdav]
listen = *:8080
ssl_webdav = False

[jsonrpc]
listen=*:8000
```

I tried also netsat command : **netstat -tupan | grep 8000** .But there is no output!!
When I run cdexe and then ./trytond --verbose to verify if the server is running or not , is shows me this error msg :

```
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,020] INFO trytond.config using /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/config/trytond.conf as configuration files
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,615] INFO trytond.modules ir:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,615] INFO trytond.modules res:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,615] INFO trytond.modules country:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,616] INFO trytond.modules currency:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,618] INFO trytond.modules tests:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,618] INFO trytond.modules webdav:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,619] INFO trytond.modules calendar:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,683] INFO trytond.modules party:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,692] INFO trytond.modules company:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,731] INFO trytond.modules account:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,756] INFO trytond.modules product:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,760] INFO trytond.modules account_product:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,763] INFO trytond.modules health:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,797] INFO trytond.modules stock:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,821] INFO trytond.modules account_invoice:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,839] INFO trytond.modules health_archives:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,844] INFO trytond.modules health_calendar:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,849] INFO trytond.modules health_contact_tracing:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,851] INFO trytond.modules health_crypto:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,854] INFO trytond.modules health_ems:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,859] INFO trytond.modules health_federation:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,952] INFO trytond.modules health_genetics:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,954] INFO trytond.modules health_gyneco:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,958] INFO trytond.modules health_icd10:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,959] INFO trytond.modules health_icd10pcs:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,960] INFO trytond.modules health_icd9procs:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,960] INFO trytond.modules health_icpm:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,961] INFO trytond.modules health_imaging:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,963] INFO trytond.modules health_iss:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,965] INFO trytond.modules health_lab:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,969] INFO trytond.modules health_lifestyle:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,971] INFO trytond.modules health_ophthalmology:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,973] INFO trytond.modules health_pediatrics:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:29,975] INFO trytond.modules health_reporting:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,597] WARNING py.warnings /home/gnuhealth/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:40: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Cursor.new is deprecated
  cursors.MOVE:          Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.FLEUR),


(trytond:7610): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 14:41:30.598: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,605] INFO trytond.modules health_socioeconomics:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,607] INFO trytond.modules health_surgery:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,611] INFO trytond.modules health_who_essential_medicines:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,612] INFO trytond.modules stock_lot:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,614] INFO trytond.modules account_invoice_stock:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,615] INFO trytond.modules health_crypto_lab:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,616] INFO trytond.modules health_disability:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,619] INFO trytond.modules health_genetics_uniprot:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,620] INFO trytond.modules health_history:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,621] INFO trytond.modules health_inpatient:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,626] INFO trytond.modules health_mdg6:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,627] INFO trytond.modules health_ntd:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,627] INFO trytond.modules health_orthanc:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,682] INFO trytond.modules health_pediatrics_growth_charts:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,683] INFO trytond.modules health_qrcodes:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,699] INFO trytond.modules health_services:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,702] INFO trytond.modules health_inpatient_calendar:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,703] INFO trytond.modules health_insurance:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,706] INFO trytond.modules health_ntd_chagas:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,707] INFO trytond.modules health_ntd_dengue:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,709] INFO trytond.modules health_nursing:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,711] INFO trytond.modules health_pediatrics_growth_charts_who:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,713] INFO trytond.modules health_profile:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,714] INFO trytond.modules health_services_lab:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,715] INFO trytond.modules purchase:registering classes
7610 140256688604992 [2020-09-03 14:41:30,724] INFO trytond.modules sale:registering classes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-5.0.25/trytond/modules/__init__.py", line 53, in import_module
    module = importlib.import_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trytond.modules.sale'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trytond", line 29, in <module>
    Pool.start()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-5.0.25/trytond/pool.py", line 102, in start
    register_classes()
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-5.0.25/trytond/modules/__init__.py", line 331, in register_classes
    the_module = import_module(module)
  File "/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-5.0.25/trytond/modules/__init__.py", line 77, in import_module
    module = spec.loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trytond/modules/sale/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import sale
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trytond/modules/sale/sale.py", line 8, in <module>
    from trytond.i18n import gettext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trytond.i18n'
```

I dont know what is wrong and what should I do .

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have mixed some tryton series. The trytond.i18n package (used by the sale module) was introduced on 5.2 series but you are running the trytond server using the 5.0 series.

In order to ensure tryton is working you should use the same series of all of the components: The server, the client and all the modules. The series is determined by the two first digits of the component version. So if you want to use the 5.0 series, all your components versions should be 5.0.x (where x is any number).

In order to fix this, I will recomend you removing all tryton components (server and modules) and resinstalling them from scratch to ensure that everything is running the right version.

Comment: tryton --version command shows : Tryton 5.6.3 and trytond --version shows: trytond 5.6.5 but I have also a trytond-5.0.25 directory . I am lost . what should I do ?

Comment: It seems you have both 5.0 and 5.6 series. Your traceback was running the 5.0 server, so you should not use 5.6 modules on it.

Comment: How can I uninstall trytond please ? I want to remove all the modules.

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. All package manager normally include an option to uninstall. If you installed from sources you just  need to remove the sources.

Comment: THen you can run "pip uninstall tryton" to remove it